# Assigning a value of veriable to property of a plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, plupload

I'm Js Newbie.

I'm trying to set a property of [Plupload](http://www.plupload.com/) using the following way.

```
$(function () {
    var myUrl = "https://" + $('input#hfBucketName').val() + $('input#hfEndPoint').val();
    $("#uploaderdiv").plupload({
        runtimes: 'html5,flash,silverlight',
        url: myUrl,
        //Removed for simplicity
    });
});
```

This gives me `Upload URL might be wrong or doesn't exist.` error when tried to upload files.

I assume I'm failing to assign the `url` property of the plugin using the calculated variable.

On Chrome console, when I type `myUrl` after the page finishes the load, I get `ReferenceError: myUrl is not defined`

But, when I type (on Console) `var myUrl = "https://" + $('input#hfBucketName').val() + $('input#hfEndPoint').val();` and then `myUrl` it gives me the value I expect.

How can I assign the `myUrl` to `url` property of the plugin? Where I'm wrong?

**EDIT**

Sorry. I've went wrong with including my code to the question. I've fixed my code block now. Actually everything is wrapped inside `$(function () { });`, while still doesn't solve my problem.

Comment: What do you get if you log `myUrl` after declaring it?

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to access the value of elements which might not have loaded yet. `$(function() {});` is jQuery shorthand for a document.ready event. Moving your myUrl variable declaration into the document ready function should fix your problem:

```
$(function () {
    var myUrl = "https://" + $('input#hfBucketName').val() + $('input#hfEndPoint').val();

    $("#uploaderdiv").plupload({
        runtimes: 'html5,flash,silverlight',
        url: myUrl,
        //Removed for simplicity
    });
});
```